# How can I configure the touchpad and keyboard settings on a Dell Inspiron 5110?

Tags: shortcut-keys, dell, touchpad, alps

I am using ubuntu 11.10.

**I want the following 3 things:**

1. I have dell inspiron 5110 laptop. There is button at the top right corner of laptop which can be used for turning the screen off. It works in windows but it does not work in ubuntu 11.10. Even in the manual of the laptop, it the button is supported only in windows. Is there a way to activate it in ubuntu 11.10?
2. Some of the keys like: "break" etc. are missing. Can I use other keys (or combinations of other keys) to function as those missing keys?
3. In the program, "mouse and touchpad", there is no tab for touchpad. I want to enable vertical and horizontal scrolling. How do I do that?

**The command:**

**xinput list**

shows

```
Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse id=13 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys
```

Please help!!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer to address the touch-pad issue:

Per Dell Forum [image]

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/t/19405246.aspx

download the touch-pad driver

http://people.canonical.com/~sforshee/alps-touchpad/psmouse-alps-0.10/psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all.deb

[source](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3525/t/19405246.aspx)

Comment: It did not solve the problem. I still can't see the tab for touchpad in "mouse and touchpad" application.

Comment: Also, /etc/X11/xorg.conf is empty