# Turn off tap to click on typing - ALPS touchpad

Tags: dell, touchpad, alps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ALPS touchpad on DELL Inspiron I15RN-3647BK with Ubuntu 11.10 x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119817/alps-touchpad-on-dell-inspiron-i15rn-3647bk-with-ubuntu-11-10-x64)

There are many questions on the site regarding the ALPS touchpads which are not recognized by Ubuntu. They behave as a PS2 mouse and the touchpad tab is missing from the mouse menu. Therefore there is no scroll option and, the most annoying thing, while typing, the cursor often jumps because I touch the touchpad. I found a program which can disable the touchpad on command: `touchpad-indicator`, which was found on the Ubuntu help page. This program seems to be able to stop and start the touchpad on command.

I was wondering how can I create a script which turns off the touchpad while typing the keyboard?

Comment: Which computer do you use? How can one determine whether he has an "ALPS" touchpad?

Comment: I use Dell N5110, and the touchpad is mentioned on Dell's website. Moreover, there are many others which deal with the same problem as me, all with Dell laptops and ALPS touchpads. For now I solved my problem by using an external keyboard while typing serious stuff, but that is not a solution I'd expect.

Comment: I see. The situation is like in http://askubuntu.com/q/154147/19753 , and http://askubuntu.com/q/141479/19753 , and http://askubuntu.com/q/111039/19753 .

Comment: One thing I did when I had a dell was to map one of the keys (I think scroll lock) to toggle the touchpad on and off. That way its up to you to hit it when you start typing and it will remain disabled until you hit it again. At least that way you have control.